Why am I receiving "non-numeric argument to binary operator" error when running a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model?
I am attempting to a run a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model. I ran an experiment where I gave adult snails a phosphorus-enriched diet and a phosphorous-depleted diets (P). These snails all come from different families; there are 10 families (Lineages). We also have 3 ploidy levels (diploid, triploid, tetraploid). Lineage is a random factor and will always be nested underneath a ploidy level. For example, Lineage A can only be diploid. It can never be triploid nor tetraploid. My dependent variable is embryo count, which is zero-inflated and the highest embryo number is 49. We measured adult length (Length) since it has a significant linear relationship with embryo number.
This is my code:
model5 <- zeroinfl(Embryonumber ~ (Ploidy/1|Lineage) + P:Ploidy + Length,
  data = x, dist = "negbin")
summary(model5)

What I think I have asked R to run is a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model. Dependent is embryo number. Ploidy and P are fixed factors and I have included them as stand-alone factors and their interaction. Length is a covariate. Lineage is random and nested in Ploidy - Lineage cannot and should not be stand alone.
But I receive this error:
Error in Ploidy/1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I have 2 ideas here: 1) the format of my data is wrong or 2) coded a random factor nested in a fixed factor wrong.
When I run summary of my data (summary (data)) I receive:
     Lineage             Ploidy               P             SnailLetterSymbol      Length       Embryonumber   
 Length:99          Length:99          Length:99          Length:99          Min.   :3.500   Min.   : 0.000  
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:4.000   1st Qu.: 2.000  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :4.100   Median : 6.000  
                                                                             Mean   :4.219   Mean   : 9.364  
                                                                             3rd Qu.:4.500   3rd Qu.:14.000  
                                                                             Max.   :5.000   Max.   :49.000  
    Presence      Standardized residuals
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :-1.405440     
 1st Qu.:1.0000   1st Qu.:-0.706935     
 Median :1.0000   Median :-0.299980     
 Mean   :0.7879   Mean   :-0.000001     
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.: 0.593960     
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   : 3.461570     

Do I need to recode my Ploidy or Lineage as a vector?
Here are the two columns in question, but let me know if you need more:

I am unsure if I used the correct syntax for nesting and random factors. I see most vignettes that random and nested factors always have the (1 | in front of both factors. I have not done this, because Ploidy is not random only Lineage is.  I have taken advice on how to nest a random factor from: 1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified?noredirect=1&lq=1
2) https://www.muscardinus.be/statistics/nested.html
3) https://rdoodles.rbind.io/2019/11/nested-random-factors-in-mixed-multilevel-or-hierarchical-models/
4) https://ourcodingclub.github.io/tutorials/mixed-models/#nested
I then attempted to use long-hand syntax (as described in link 2) but I receive an error. Code:
model5 <- zeroinfl(Embryonumber ~ (Ploidy:1|Lineage) + P:Ploidy + Length,
  data = x, dist = "negbin")
summary(model5)

Error: Error in Ploidy:1 : NA/NaN argument
Do you all have any advice?
Thank you!
An update: I have attempted the below code and I still receive the Error in Ploidy/Lineage : non-numeric argument to binary operator.
 model4 <- zeroinfl(Embryonumber ~ (1 | Ploidy / Lineage) + P:Ploidy + Length| Presence,
  data = x, dist = "negbin")
summary(model4)

As s commenter suggested I removed the nested factor, which is not an appropriate model for my data, but I wanted to at least test that the function works. Code:
model4 <- zeroinfl(Embryonumber ~ (1 | Lineage) + (1 | Ploidy) + P:Ploidy + Length| Presence,
  data = x, dist = "negbin")
summary(model4)

Error:
Error in 1 | Lineage : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types


As described at your first link, (1|group1/group2) is a nested random effect estimating an intercept where group2 is nested within group1.  I think this is what you want, either 1 | Lineage / Ploidy or 1 | Ploidy / Lineaage -- I'm not quite sure which one from your description. It doesn't make sense to have / on left hand side of | because / describes a group nesting structure, and groups go on the right hand side of |. Nor does it make sense to interact a categorical variable with 1 as you attempt in (Ploidy:1|Lineage).

@GregorThomas Thank you for the advice. I am a little confused about the "1 | ". I thought it represented designation of a random factor so that is why I put this "1 | " in front of the random factor "Lineage". Ploidy is a fixed factor. But instead "1 | " denotes the inclusion of random intercept. To clarify,  "1 | " can go in front of group nesting structures that include fixed factors, yes?

1 | Group means you want to fit a random intercept term for each group. ... + 1 | Lineage would fit a random intercept term for each lineage. (1 | Lineage / Ploidy) is the same as (1 | Lineage) + (1 | Lineage:Ploidy) and these would fit a random intercept for Lineage and each Ploidy nested within it. (1 | Lineage) + (1 | Ploidy) will fit a random intercept for each lineage and a separate one for each ploidy.  Ploidy : 1 makes no sense, so Ploidy : 1 | Lineage makes no sense.

Based on your description of your data, I'd just do (1 | Lineage) + (1 | Ploidy).

@GregorThomas Thank you for your advice! I think I will try (1 | Ploidy / Lineage). Lineage is a random factor that is nested in ploidy. Ploidy is a fixed factor.


zeroinfl doesn't handle random effects, so the only bar (|) in your formula should be the one splitting the conditional from the zero-inflation model, e.g.

Embryonumber ~ Lineage + P*Ploidy + Length| Presence


if you do want to incorporate random effect in a ZINB model, you could try glmmTMB, e.g.

library(glmmTMB)
glmmTMB(Embryonumber ~ P*Ploidy + Length + (1|Lineage),
    ziformula = ~ Presence,
  data = x, family = "nbinom2")


I would not recommend using Ploidy as a random effect grouping variable; for a random effect grouping variable, you need (1) enough levels to estimate an among-group variance (≥ 5 is a typical rule of thumb) and (2) you need the levels to be exchangeable, i.e. the labels of the levels could be switched without changing the meaning of the model, which I suspect is not true for ploidy.
you don't need to worry about the nesting of lineages within ploidy levels, that gets handled automatically


Thank you for your help! This model worked without any issues or errors. I did change the  "P*Ploidy" to "P:Ploidy" because I wanted to include P and Ploidy as standalone variables, but correct me if I am wrong.
@BenBolker, I am a little curious. What handles the nesting of ploidy? Is it the package? And why does it (likely the package) do that?
I am going to learn how to interpret the output now! Thank you again  for your help!

For nesting vs crossing, maybe read https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/2126 . P*Ploidy and P:Ploidy should give you models with the same overall fit, but parameterized differently. The emmeans package might help with comparisons ...

Thank you very much! I just talked with my advisor and she agreed with your original code - that "P*Ploidy" is the syntax for stand alone factors and interaction of factors. Thanks again! I have some reading to do, but I am just relieved the the model works now.

If this solved your problem you can click the check-mark to accept it.
